# Django admin - Allow manual editing of auto DateTime fields

Tags: django, django-admin

Is it possible to allow manual editing of auto DateTimeField's on the add / change page of a model. The fields are defined as:

```
post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
post_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I'm not sure how manually overriding these would exactly work, is the auto updating handled at the database level or in django itself?

Comment: the auto updating gets handled in `pre_save` method of `DateTimeField`, at Django level.

Comment: Everything is possible but it could be easier if you'd tell us how exactly you want those field to behave. I think it would be better to use ``default=datetime.datetime.now`` for ``post_date`` field and tweak inital value for ``post_updated`` field in **Form**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`auto_now_add=True` and `auto_now=True` [assume](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L658) `editable=False`. So if you need to correct this field, don't use them.

Auto updating handles at django level. For example, if you update queryset, e.g.

```
Article.object.filter(pk=10).update(active=True)
```

won't update `post_updated` field. But

```
article = Article.object.get(pk=10)
article.active = True
atricle.save()
```

will do

Answer (score 3):

`auto_now_add=True` and `auto_now=True` assume `editable=False`. So if you need to modify this field in the admin or in any other `ModelForm`, then don't use the `auto_now_*=True` settings.

Automatic updating of these `auto_now_*` fields is handled at the Django level.

If you update an instance of a model with an `auto_now_*=True` field, then Django will automatically update the field, e.g.,

```
class Article(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
article = Article.object.get(pk=10)
article.active = True
article.save()
# ASSERT: article.updated has been automatically updated with the current date and time
```

If you want to override this automatic behavior in Django, you can do so by updating the instance via queryset.update(), e.g.,

```
Article.object.filter(pk=10).update(active=True)
# ASSERT: Article.object.get(pk=10).updated is unchanged

import datetime
Article.object.filter(pk=10).update(updated=datetime.datetime(year=2014, month=3, day=21))
# ASSERT: article.updated == March 21, 2014
```